# MySQL performance with large WHERE IN() clause

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

Let's say we have a table with 4 columns: `id (int 11, indexed), title, content, category (varchar 5)`.

I have a user select a category. Each category can contain up to 999 objects. Using `SELECT id FROM table WHERE category = ?` I get a list of all objects.

I then have the user select/deselect some of the objects. After which I need to select the content of the remaining selected objects.

Now my question is as follows, should I worry about performance when using `SELECT content FROM table WHERE id IN($array)`? Would it be better to use `SELECT content FROM table WHERE category = ? AND id IN($array)`. The idea here being I filter it down to 999 objects before performing the IN...

Does this make any sense? Or should I not be using the `IN()` at all?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance too much until you have tens of thousands of rows and even then, with proper indexing, you shouldn't have to worry about performance too much.

Comment: Read up on MySQL's EXPLAIN syntax and use that to understand the difference in your two queries

Comment: `category` should be indexed

Comment: Would a CTE help out here? Run the CTE on the category query then just do a select where on the CTE.

Comment: MySQL does not yet have CTE features see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html

Comment: The most obvious thing would be to index your category column, but I suspect your database design isn't right.  It would almost certainly be a better idea to store the categories in a separate table and use foreign keys to associate an entry in the main table with an entry in the category table

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you always have `content` showing on the screen?

999 is a *long* list to put on the screen.  Re-think your UI.

When selected/deselected, what happens?  Do you gray out the `content`?  If so, that is a UI issue, not a database issue.  If you store the subset that is currently "selected", then how/where is that stored?  And, do you want to store it after each select/deselect?  Or wait until he clicks "Submit"?

In other words, I don't see why this is a database question.

Back to the queries in question:

```
INDEX(category)
SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE category = ...; -- This is optimal

PRIMARY KEY(id)
SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE id IN (...); -- optimal for an arbitrary set

INDEX(category, id)
SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE category = ... AND id IN (...)
    -- use this only if you both parts are needed for filtering
    -- not for optimizing
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rick, it really clarifies things. And I know 999 items is a lot, but that's a maximum. In reality I expect 50 to 100 rows per category. Each row has about 20 cells decimal(6,2) or varchar(10). Rows are displayed in a table, and value's can be edited (either per row or all rows in batch, which is why I have to display them all). After editing, a text file is created for each row using a template... I realize that php/sql is far from the best choice to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but it's the language I kinda know... so yeah ^_^